# $GL_2(R)$ and $\mathbb{A}_4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

So, i have to prove that $\mathbb{A}_4$ is not isomorphic to a subgroup $G$ of $GL_2(R)$.

Here is a "hint" (are previuos part of the same problem that i was thinking, so i supose should help):

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ of $GL_2(R)$isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$,
there would be 2 matrices $A,B$ such that $AB=BA$,  $A^2=B^2=I$, in wich case $A,B$ are simultaneosly diagonalizables, so $H$ is the conjugated of a subgroup of diagonal matrices...wich i dont know how to use to prove the affirmation about hte isomorphism

Comment: What about $\begin{bmatrix}\pm 1\\&\pm 1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: You are right, my mistake i just was making another exercise before and confuse the sum notation with the product... so i have to review my idea, thanks

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal?

Comment: I am studying groups, rings and modules, but if you have another idea i would like to hear it

Comment: Have you done much representation theory?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No, not at all

Comment: That's too bad. Need to think of something else then.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen i have edited the question, so basically the idea i was is a"hint" but i am not sure how, maybe you have some idea

Answer (score 1):

The observation that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable does help. Proffering the following route.

Assume that a subgroup $G\le GL_2(\Bbb{R})$ isomorphic to $A_4$ would exist. Because we can replace $G$ by any of its conjugates, we may as well assume that the matrices
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}-1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)\qquad\text{and}\qquad
B=\left(\begin{array}{rr}1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right)
$$
are both elements of $G$ (ask, if you need details for this). Then comes the hint.

1. Let $K$ be the subgroup generated by $A$ and $B$. Let $N=N_{GL_2}(K)$ be the normalizer of $K$ in $GL_2(\Bbb{R})$. Show that $N$ consists of the so called monomial matrices
   $$
   N=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{rr}a&0\\0&b\end{array}\right)\,\big\vert\, a,b\in\Bbb{R}^*\right\}\cup \left\{\left(\begin{array}{rr}0&a\\b&0\end{array}\right)\,\big\vert\, a,b\in\Bbb{R}^*\right\}.
   $$
2. Show that there are no elements of order $3$ in $N$.
3. Show that $G$ cannot exist.

Comment: To do step 1 it may help to observe that a matrix $S$ commutes with either $A$ or $B$, iff $S$ is diagonal itself. Conjugation by a non-diagonal element of $N$ intechanges $A$ and $B$.

Comment: If we were allowed to use representation theory, it would follow immediately from the character table of $A_4$ that there are no faithful representations of degree two (even complex ones!). Those tools were now disallowed, so the above is the simplest substitute I could come up with. Taking advantage of the assumption that we are only interested in real matrices :-)

Comment: Thanks, i am gonna review the details, (the part to assume tha A and B have that form) and in part 3, i should prove that G is not cointain in N? so will follow that G is not isomorphic to $A_4$

Comment: And, by the wayy, this semester i am probably gonna take a course of representation theory, so i should be able to undesrtand better your comment :p, thanks again for the help

Comment: The subgroup generated by the corresponding elements $A=(12)(34)$ and $B=(13)(24)$ is normal in $A_4$.

Comment: Yes i now,but i wasnt sure how to prove that G is not in N